# Is it possible to tell a batch file to analayse all data after a certain character?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code to find the square roots of numbers. However, because it's batch, it doesn't support floating point numbers. I wanted to allow people to input floating point numbers, and then for my code to be able to know how many digits came after the decimal place, and then shift it up however many positions is required for it to become a positive integer, which batch can work with.

Is this possible?

If not, do you know of any other code that will allow me to do square root calculations with decimal number?

This is my existing code for square roots:

```
@echo off
color 16
Title SquareRoot

:StartSquareRoot
cls
echo Number:
set /p number=
call :SquareRoot %number%
echo Square: %number%
echo Root: %answer%
pause
goto StartSquareRoot

:SquareRoot
SETLOCAL
    EnableDelayedExpansion
set root=1
set /a sqr=%root%*%root%

:Loop
if %sqr% LSS %number% (
    set /a root=!root!+1
    set /a sqr=!root!*!root!
    goto Loop
)
(EndLocal && set answer=%root% && exit /B)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See `Set /?` for getting from a character position to end of string      `%PATH:~10,5%`
 _would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
remainder of the variable value._ **OR** Use a `for /f` loop delimiting on decimal point. See `For /?`.

Comment: Please make sure that `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` is on the one line, and `set root=1` should be `set root=%1`. Also `set /a sqr=%root%*%root%` and `set /a sqr=!root!*!root!` should be `set /a sqr=root*root`

Comment: ...and similarly, `set /a root=!root!+1` should be `set /a root+=1`. You'll then realise you probably didn't need to enable delayed expansion for the existing code!

Answer (score 0):

With your "comma-shifting" method, you are still bound to INT32. If your numbers are too big (after shifting), you get incorrect results or errormessages.

Better use (the help of) a programming language that can do proper math (like Powershell):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set /p "num=Number: "
for /f %%a in ('"powershell [math]::sqrt(%num%)"') do set "sqrt=%%a"
for /f %%a in ('"powershell %num%*%num%"') do set "sq=%%a"
echo Squareroot of %num% is %sqrt%, Square is %sq%
```

The quoting `... ('" command "') ...` is a bit unusual, but removes the need for escaping special characters, `)` in this case)